# Magento 2: Customer not able to login on multi-website second website

Tags: magento2, customer, login

I have a multiwebsite on 2.4.3p1 with urls xyz.com and xyz.com/wholesale. The customer is not able to login from the wholesale website. It is redirecting to the login page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

can u please provide what error is coming , or can u try in incognito mode , there may be issues that sometimes the cookie value is setting in another domain , so trying in private window may help , or do please share the error message , so that i can help you with this further.Thank you !.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set customer account global.
Admin setting:

Store -> configuration -> Customer -> Customer Configuration -> Account sharing option -> Share Customer Account = Global

[image: Admin configuration setting]